# append div before last child in jQuery 1.3

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery 1.3.(x) (don't remember the exact version name).
I have a variable `holder` that contains elements.
I would like to add a div at the n-1 position inside holder.
In jquery 1.4 I can do `holder.children().last().before('<div />');`.
How can I do it using jquery 1.3?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("<div>New DIV</div>").insertBefore($(":last-child", holder));
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Chandu/u94gV/

Comment: I have the holder as a variable and not as selector. If I has a selector I could do $("#holder :last-child").before('<div/>');.